# Dictionary values don't remain constant

Tags: python

The final values are different from than during individual key fills, when key "0" is getting filled with

```
{0: (0, 0), 1: (1, 0), 2: (2, 0), 3: (3, 0), 4: (4, 0),
 5: (5, 0), 6: (6, 0), 7: (7, 0), 8: (8, 0), 9: (9, 0),
 10: (10, 0), 11: (11, 0), 12: (12, 0)
```

etc; these values are changed once the outer while loop is fully completed. They turn into:

```
{0: (0, 0), 1: (0, 0), 2: (-1, 0), 3: (-2, 0), 4: (-3, 0), 
 5: (-4, 0), 6: (-5, 0), 7: (-6, 0), 8: (-7, 0), 9: (-8, 0), 
 10: (-9, 0), 11: (-10, 0), 12: (-11, 0)
```

I'm not able to figure out why. Any help is much appreciated. You can uncomment the print statement for reference.

The code:

```
import numpy as np
from math import cos,sin,pi

ANGLE_ACCURACY = 0.5

noOfAnglesLimit = (360.0/ANGLE_ACCURACY)*0.5
angle = 0

polarLut = dict()
inner = dict()

while angle<noOfAnglesLimit:
    theta = (pi/180.0)*(angle*ANGLE_ACCURACY)

    radius = 0
    while radius<=200:
        x = int(float(radius)*cos(theta)+0.5)
        y = int(float(radius)*sin(theta)+0.5)
        inner[radius] = (x,y)
        radius+=1        

    polarLut[angle] = inner
    #print(polarLut)
    angle+=1

import json

with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
     file.write(json.dumps(polarLut))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have one `inner` dictionary, which you assign to all values of the `polarLut` dictionary, then go on modifying it again for the next `angle`.

You'll want something like

```
polarLut = dict()

while angle < noOfAnglesLimit:
    theta = (pi / 180.0) * (
        angle * ANGLE_ACCURACY
    )
    inner = dict()
    radius = 0
    while radius <= 200:
        x = int(float(radius) * cos(theta) + 0.5)
        y = int(float(radius) * sin(theta) + 0.5)
        inner[radius] = (x, y)
        radius += 1

    polarLut[angle] = inner
    angle += 1
```

instead.

Also, I would suggest using `for angle in range(noOfAnglesLimit)` instead, it's more Pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

You are always storing the same dictionary inside `polarLut`, so all the entries point to the same original `inner`.

Move the declaration of `inner` inside your while loop.